# Removing the background of a vertical menu li element on hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this vertical that i am trying to customize

```
<ul class="tracking_nav nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">  
<li class="tracking_list_type" style=".tracking_list_type:hover{background-color:none !important}">  
<a href="#"><span class="topinfo"><span class="number_plates"><img src="u_online.gif" />Number 10</span></span><span class="moving_status">76 moving</span><br/><span class="link_text">Brother David Cameroon</span></a><span class="linkso"><a href="">Tracking</a><a href="">Playback</a><a href="">Commands</a></span></li>     
<li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>  
<li><a href="#">Practice Editor </a></li>   
<li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>   
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>   
</ul>
```

This is the css

```
moving_status{
        float:right;
        color:#76EE00;
        font-weight:bold;
        }
        .linkso{margin-left:13px;}
        .topinfo{
        display:inline-block;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        }
        .linkso > a{
        margin-right:4px;
        }
```

This is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/codebreaker87/eoo87zkk/

I have tried `.tracking_list_type > li:hover{background-color:none !important;}` but i cant seem to target the li element.How can i fix this?.

Comment: are you referring to the background that appears on hover?

Comment: Yes.I forgot to add that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target hover backgrounds with `:hover`.  For your case, you need the following:

```
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover
```

However I would recommend

```
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover
```

Comment: This `.nav-tabs>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover` worked. Thanks